# Spring web service get method not working

Tags: angular, spring-boot, web-services

The Angular call to a web service GET method is not working

I have created a spring boot web service. It works on the browser, but when I call it from the Angular code it does not. I have checked the URL on the browser and it works. The URL I use on the angular code is correct. On the web browser I am using `http://localhost:8080/rofile/roles/find/9` on the `findbyId()` is also the same.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/find/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public RoleVO findRole(@PathVariable("id") Long id)
{
    return roleService.findById(id);
}
```

```
public findById(id: number) {
    return this.http.get(this.rolesUrl + '/find/' + id);
}
```

I expected the call to the web service method to go through. But it seems as if the web service call is not getting through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most frequent issue again, Http uses rxjs and is observable, meaning that you should subscribe to it to make it work.

Inject the service in your component and call **`.subscribe()`**

```
 this.yourService.findById(id)
  .subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I had injected the service but I was not calling ```subscribe()```.

Comment: `The most frequent issue again`, why not then mark as a duplicate?